# biblatex prenote postnote font size

Tags: biblatex, formatting, fontsize, footcite

Currently i try to resize the prenote and postnote.
There is: `\renewcommand*{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{10}{10}}` for it.
But that only changes one part for `\footcite[prenote][postnote]{blabla}`.
`prenote` and `postnote` are unfortunately not adjusted with it.
So I'm looking for something along the lines of `\prenotesize` and `\postnotesize`.

Template: https://github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template

That doesn't work either:

```latex
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkextblxfootcite]
  {\fontsize{10}{10}\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\fontsize{10}{10}\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \fontsize{10}{10}\usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\fontsize{10}{10}\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to resize only pre- and postnotes, the citation output will probably look a bit inhomogeneous. Plus footnotes are already a bit smaller at `\footnotesize`, so going even smaller might not be to good an idea.

The easiest way to change the formatting of these fields is via `\DeclareFieldFormat`. Below I have taken the original definitions from `biblatex.def` and added a font sizing command

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-ibid, autocite=footnote,]{biblatex}


\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{\scriptsize#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\scriptsize\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[cf.][381]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: cf. Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 381]

Note that `\fontsize{<font size>}{<line spacing>}` needs a `\selectfont` afterwards in order to work properly. So `\fontsize{10}{10}` on its own will usually not do anything useful. You need `\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont`.